# What is safebrowsing.google.com ?Does it impact the security testing?

Tags: penetration-test, attack-prevention, google, firefox

I recently security tested my web application using Firefox browser and while pentesting my webapplication i noticed [safebrowsing.google.com](http://safebrowsing.google.com),while i diged more about it ,i could able to retreive only the following information :

```
POST https://safebrowsing.google.com/safebrowsing/downloads?client=navclient-auto-ffox&appver=30.0&pver=2.2&key=AIzaSyD-s-mXL4mBzF7KMRkhTCIbG2RKnRGXzJc HTTP/1.1
Host: safebrowsing.google.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:30.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/30.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Content-Length: 5148
Content-Type: text/plain
Cookie: PREF=ID=d802a963ac565a49:TM=1430816056:LM=1430816056:S=Mcs7IJmXmv8slghn; NID=67=m9-42qMKY6sRGB-KSRsiFYfjsijMBZqa_w5DJnXmT3x2c2IOBVv6IezuvZ-CX9wqAvyeFJ_VXkF9FDMuC1bDSYlt0rnxiYbIWQJsfMTG1cGLoFKfK-QYhPkLgAo0Ybxi
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

Now my questions were few:

does google spy's on my security tests?if so how could i prevent from it.

what is safebrowsing.google.com?why it get recorded at my scripts

My test environment is as follows :

browser : firefox version 38 with no addons

pentesting tool : zapproxy of owsap

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firefox takes hashes of various page parameters (mainly URL segments) and passes them back as part of Google's SafeBrowsing scheme. It cannot readily identify parameters or other information that you pass to the target - it's just used to check against a list of known attack domains.

As per [these instructions](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/922449), you can turn SafeBrowse off:

> Firefox button > Options > Options (or Tools > Options) > Security, un-check both "Block reported attack sites" and "Block reported web forgeries"

Comment: Also related: [What Firefox settings should be changed from factory defaults to ensure privacy?](https://github.com/pyllyukko/user.js)